# Powering a Raspberry Pi without a micro USB cable

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, alternative-power

I want to attach a Raspberry Pi to hardware I'm developing. There is already +5v and GND available on the hardware. Is there any way to power up my Raspberry Pi from this (I just wanna avoid another micro USB cable inside my hardware if possible). Is there any safe way to so it through any GPIO pins?.

Answer (score 7):

The safer is to connect between PP1 (5V) and PP5 (GND).
You don't bypass the power fuse of the RPi.
[image: RPi power mod]

Comment: @Foxrider83m yes, your suggestion is the safest and also most reliable..

Comment: @Foxrider83  somehow, I couldn't see the point PP1. I saw PP5. I am using Raspberry Pi 3- Model B+

Comment: You can find the schematic of the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ [on the official web page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3bplus_1p0_reduced.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. So I guess PP2(5v) is fine!!

Comment: You can also power the PI from the hat. Some informations are defined https://github.com/raspberrypi/hats/blob/master/designguide.md#back-powering-the-pi-via-the-j8-gpio-header

Answer (score 3):

You can’t power the Pi through GPIO, but you can power through the 5V and Gnd pins on the expansion header.

This is perfectly safe and acceptable, provided the supply complies. HATs often do this and the Foundation has compliance recommendations.

Indeed in some Pi models (including the Pi4) these are directly connected to the power connectors.

Comment: i need to connect a touch screen to pi using HDMI and a relay to GPIO. Do you think that it gonna meet all the power requirements?

Comment: What power requirements?  You haven't told us 1) which power supply you will use, or 2) how much the Pi and the peripherals you plan to connect need.