# Raspberry Pi Low Power warning when connecting without USB cable

Tags: alternative-power

I'm trying to connect power to Raspberry Pi 3B+ directly without USB cable, as in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/100744/112959). I've tried both connecting the 5V and GND extension pins as in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100745/112959) and connecting to PP2 and PP5 according to [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100788/112959). But I get low power warning even though the voltage should be enough, I've even increased up to more than 6V (I've measured 5.9V when using the USB adapter). I've tried both a Mean Well LRS-50-5 switching power supply (5V, 10A adjustable ±0.5V), and one from [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/658) (5V, 10A). I'm attaching cables on a breadboard, but I've measured the voltage directly on the Pi as well. What could be the problem?

Comment: Don't use a breadboard for the Pi's power. Use direct cable connections to the Pi's 5V and GND with no joints and sensibly sized cable.

Comment: I've measured on other components on the breadboard to make sure that the voltage doesn't drop, but maybe there are other effects I'm not seeing (time variations?). I'll try connecting directly and get back.

Comment: If you get a low power indication the cause will be the same as the hundreds of similar questions - **low quality power supply AND/OR poor quality wiring**. If you supply more than 5.25V you will eventually damage the Pi.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Comment: Soldering instead of using a breadboard solved the problem. Thanks @CoderMike.

Comment: @Milliways yes, thanks for the link, the power supplies were fine, but not the wiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using the breadboard. After I soldered the wires instead, the Adafruit power supply worked fine.